# Failed igraph installation on a Ubuntu box

Tags: python-2.7, installation, igraph

I tried installing igraph using easy_install, and received a message to contact the package's author or the easy_install maintainers. Knowing that igraph has a pretty active community in SO, I am pasting the message below:

```
sudo easy_install python-igraph
Searching for python-igraph
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-igraph/
Best match: python-igraph 0.7.1-2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-igraph/python-igraph-0.7.1-2.tar.gz#md5=4b1f4dc621fc938434836e59dea31173
Processing python-igraph-0.7.1-2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-R2pEQ_/python-igraph-0.7.1-2/setup.cfg
Running python-igraph-0.7.1-2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-R2pEQ_/python-igraph-0.7.1-2/egg-dist-tmp-bl3Z_7
Cannot find the C core of igraph on this system using pkg-config.
We will now try to download and compile the C core from scratch.
Version number of the C core: 0.7.1-2
We will also try: 0.7.1

error: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('/usr/local/bin/tmp', 511) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

My machine already has C/C++. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This must be a new feature of `easy_install`. The Python setup script tried to download the C core of igraph (since you have not installed it earlier) into a temporary directory that is outside `easy_install`'s sandbox. Earlier versions had no problems with it whatsoever. I'll try to dig into `easy_install`'s code to see if there is an easy workaround.

Comment: By the way, it's interesting; igraph tries to download the source code of the C core into `/usr/local/bin/tmp`, which is weird. It is supposed to figure out the absolute path of `setup.py` and then create a `tmp` subdirectory there. `easy_install` must be doing something behind the scenes that prevents `setup.py` from detecting its own path properly.

Comment: For the record, you can follow the updates on this bug here: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/21

Comment: @Tamás: Thanks. I subscribed for notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one workaround here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/680. Try installing the C library directly; easy_install worked following this. In case you encounter import error for igraph, update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable to include the location with igraph executable (usually /usr/local/bin).